# Как сделать диапазон в календаре angular 2?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Всем привет!
У меня есть календарь и надо сделать диапазон даты. При первом клике выбираю первую дату, а при втором - вторую. Выбирается первая дата, следующим образом:

```
onClickDate(day, monthIndex, year) {
 this.selectedDay = day;
 this.selectedMonth = this.months[monthIndex];
 this.selectedYear = year;
 this.startDate = new Date(year, monthIndex, day);

// вот здесь подумал, типа если startDate не пустой, тогда 
// выбирать вторую дату 

 if (!this.startDate) {
    this.selectEndDate(day, monthIndex, year);
 }
}

selectEndDate(day, monthIndex, year) {
 this.selectedDay = day;
 this.selectedMonth = this.months[monthIndex];
 this.selectedYear = year;
 this.endDate = new Date(year, monthIndex, day);
}
```

При работе, выбирает одну дату на диапазон. Напишите хотя бы логику, пожалуйста. Как решить задачу?

Comment: Сделай два поля вводы для даты.

Answer (score 0):

По второму клики startDate перезаписывается, вероятно, подойдет что то вроде такого:

```
onClickDate(day, monthIndex, year) {

  this.selectedDay = day;
  this.selectedMonth = this.months[monthIndex];
  this.selectedYear = year;
  if (!this.startDate) {
    this.startDate = new Date(year, monthIndex, day);
  } else {
    this.endDate = new Date(year, monthIndex, day);
  }

}
```

соответственно: this.selected[Day/Month/Year] примут значение конца диапазона, если они должны хранить начало диапазона, то внести true блок if`а